# How to change oxygen window decorator?

Tags: kubuntu, themes, kde, kde4, oxygen

I am using kubuntu 12.04 and kde 4.9 and I would like to make some custom theming.

I have made some changes in my color scheme and icons and now I would like to make changes into window decoration in order to match. Although there are quite a lot of downloadable window decorators via System Settings > Workspace Appearance > Window Decorations, I have to admit that I didn't find any with so many configuration options nor appearence as default's oxygen. However, oxygen default's color (light grey) do not match with my new color set, so I would like to know if it possible to change its colors.

I have tried with several scheme colors with no success ( System Settings -> Application Appearance -> Colors -> Colors tab -> Color set: Window -> change Normal Background). Although they do change window's titles color's background in other windows decorators, oxygen ignores that configuration. I am wondering why, since it's supposed to be very customizable and multi-purpose.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Are you referring to the overall grey background colour of the windows? It sounds like you are looking for the ***Window Background*** setting.

[image: KDE4 System Colour Settings]

**Long answer (for others):**

If you are looking to change the colour appearance of KDE's windows, you can change that easily by going to 
*System Settings* > *Application Appearance*

Choose the *Colours* tab on the left.

When tweaking it yourself, the specific colour (I think) you are referring to, is under the *Colours* tab. Make sure *Common Colours* is selected as the *Colour Set* and then select a new colour for the *Window Background*.

You can also adjust quickly by choosing an existing colour scheme or setting your own scheme. On the Scheme tab you can quickly select an overall colour scheme, like e.g. *Obsidian Coast* will make all your main window background areas dark.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the problem is due to the fact that I am using QtCurve as Widget style instead of using defaults and I need to use Qt Curve as window decorator if I am to have a matching color theme. I find this really annoying, since I love Oxygen window decorator.

Comment: Finally I found out that the problem was that my custom qt curve style was overriding the general settings. After editing qt curve style I have been able to integrate oxygen window decorator with qtcurve